# The 'pip==20.0.2' distribution was not found and is required by the application

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I'm trying to install and use Python 3.11 on ubuntu 20.04
At the moment I'm having problem with the '**pip3**'
It was installed using the following command:

```
apt install python3-pip
```

when I execute the following command:

```
python3.11 -m pip --version
```

it shows correct output:

```
pip 23.0 from /home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip (python 3.11)
```

however, when I try this: '`pip3 --version`' - it returns an error:

```
/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:123: PkgResourcesDeprecationWarning: 0.1.36ubuntu1 is an invalid version and will not be supported in a future release
  warnings.warn(
/home/semyuel/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:123: PkgResourcesDeprecationWarning: 0.23ubuntu1 is an invalid version and will not be supported in a future release
  warnings.warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/semyuel/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 581, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/home/semyuel/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 909, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/semyuel/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 800, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (pip 23.0 (/home/semyuel/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages), Requirement.parse('pip==20.0.2'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/home/semyuel/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3259, in <module>
    @_call_aside
     ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/semyuel/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3234, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/semyuel/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3272, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/semyuel/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 583, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/semyuel/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 596, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/semyuel/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 795, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==20.0.2' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

Comment: Does `PATH="/home/myuser/.local/bin:$PATH" pip3 --version` work?